# Landing page field - pass value to new user form fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a single field on my landing page which I want to use to accept a field of user data collected in the full signup form.  I'd like to pass the landing page field value to the new_user_registration_path so that the full signup form has it pre-populated.  I'm trying:

```
form_for Candidate.new, url: new_candidate_registration_path(:zip => :zip )
= f.text_field :zip, class: 'input', placeholder: 'Your Zip Code'
= f.submit
```

but I am getting a post error and the zip from the first form is not being passed.  How do I achieve this functionality?

routes:

```
         cancel_candidate_registration GET    /candidates/cancel(.:format)                            candidates/registrations#cancel
                 candidate_registration POST   /candidates(.:format)                                   candidates/registrations#create
             new_candidate_registration GET    /candidates/register(.:format)                          candidates/registrations#new
            edit_candidate_registration GET    /candidates/edit(.:format)                              candidates/registrations#edit
                                        PATCH  /candidates(.:format)                                   candidates/registrations#update
                                        PUT    /candidates(.:format)                                   candidates/registrations#update
                                        DELETE /candidates(.:format)                                   candidates/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: Why don`t you just put in form data as a hidden field?

Comment: There's business logic requiring it to be repeated and editable in the full form

Comment: You are aware that the solution you are suggesting is gonna add the zip as `GET` parameter to your URL? Do a `bundle exec rake routes` and tell me how that path looks like

Comment: I still don't get your question. As you know http is not stateful so you can pass params to the server either by get our post. What is the problem now?

Comment: I want: 1.  User enters zip code on home page and clicks link 2. zip code is passed into the new candidate form and prepopulates that input

Comment: Still, using it as a field of second form is the way to go. You want it to be editable, then don't make it hidden.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your train of thought here.  It's already a field in the second form and making a hidden field hasn't been a consideration.  My question is how to set up the link on the landing page to pass the value to the second form so that it populates that value.

Comment: First form passes value of zip to controller, controller passes it to the view of second form. Basic MVC

Comment: Just add a `method: :get` to your form.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't question why you want to do it but if you want to hack it you can create new custom action or pass the param into session and use from there in your view.

I can see you're using devise, so not to get buried in details, you can:

Create your candidates controller and add create action to it

```
class CandidatesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if paras[:candidate]
      session[:zip] ||= params[:candidate][:zip]
      redirect_to new_candidate_registration_path
    else
      redirect_to :back
      flash[:error] = "man, where's the zip?"
    end 
  end
end
```

add new path to your routes.rb

```
resources :candidates, only: [:create]
```

Remove URL from your form, as Rails will submit to new controller by matching name of the model.

Now you should be able to use your session in your view to populate the the form.

Simply use `value: session[:zip]`